# Python 3.6: create new dict using values from another as indices

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

In Python 3.6.3, I have the following dict `D1`:

```
D1 = {0: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64), 1: array([0,4], dtype=int64)}
```

Each value inside the array is the index of the key of another dict `D2`:

```
D2 = {'Jack': 1, 'Mike': 2, 'Tim': 3, 'Paul': 4, 'Tommy': 5}
```

I am trying to create a third dict, `D3`, with the same keys as `D1`, and as values the keys of `D2` corresponding to the indices of `D1.values()`.

The result I am aiming for is:

```
D3 = {0: ['Mike','Tim','Paul'], 1: ['Jack','Tommy']}
```

My approach is partial in that I struggle to figure out how to tell `D3` to get the keys from `D1` and the values from `D2`. I am not too sure about that `and`. Any ideas?

```
D3 = {key:list(D1.values())[v] for key in D1.keys() and v in D2[v]}
```

Comment: You say that "Each value inside the array is the index of the key of another dict D2:" Wouldn't that mean that Jack would be 0 and Tommy would be 4? Is D2 ordered?

Comment: `D2` isn't ordered. I don't care about the order in this case.

Comment: Are you attempting to find Jack based on the value of 1 or based on the positional "index" of 0?

Comment: I am using its index.

Comment: @FaCoffee Index positions at dictionaries before Python 3.7 were not guaranteed. What Python version are you using?

Comment: dicts are not necessarily ordered so it does not have an "index" per se. If instead you are using an OrderedDict then what you are trying to do is possible https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Updated my question. I am using Python 3.6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.6+ you can use `enumerate` to create a dict to look up the names in `D2` by index, and then map the indices in `D1` to it:

```
r = dict(enumerate(D2))
D3 = {k: list(map(r.get, v)) for k, v in D1.items()}
```

D3 would become:

```
{0: ['Mike', 'Tim', 'Paul'], 1: ['Jack', 'Tommy']}
```

Comment: does this assume Python > 3.6? I cannot see how else one can trust `enumerate` with dict keys.

Comment: Are you sure about that? How else are the keys paired with 0, 1, ... ? Why is `0` grouped with `'Jack'` and not, say, `"Paul"`?

Comment: It is giving me results as `{0: ['Mike', 'Jack', 'Paul'], 1: ['Tim', 'Tommy']}` in Python 2.7 which is not what you have posted as the output

Comment: @Ev.Kounis My apologies. You're right. Had a brain malfunction moment. By using `enumerate` this does require dict keys to be in the same order as they are written and hence Python 3.6+. I've updated my answer to note it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a dict-comprehension like so:

```
from numpy import array


D1 = {0: array([1, 2, 3]), 1: array([0,4])}
D2 = {'Jack': 1, 'Mike': 2, 'Tim': 3, 'Paul': 4, 'Tommy': 5}

temp = dict(zip(D2.values(), D2.keys()))  # inverting key-value pairs

D3 = {k: [temp.get(i+1, 'N\A') for i in v] for k, v in D1.items()}
```

which results in:

```
{0: ['Mike', 'Tim', 'Paul'], 1: ['Jack', 'Tommy']}
```

Comment: Unhashable type: list. I am using Python 3 - should have said that. `list(D2.values())` is a list of lists.

Comment: @FaCoffee I am not using lists are dict keys.. Are you sure that you are running the correct thing?

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but I believe this should get you headed in the right direction. I find it helpful sometimes to break out a complicated one-liner into multiple lines

```
D3={}
for d1k,d1v in D1.items():
    D3[d1k] = []
    for idx in d1v:
        D3[d1k].append(D2[idx])
```

Comment: the indexes stored as values in `D2` are 1-based so you have to shift them.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the best solution but works

```
D3={}
for key in D1.keys():
    value_list=D1.get(key)

    value_list= [(lambda x: x+1)(x) for x in value_list]
    temp=[]
    for d2_key,value in D2.items():
        if value in value_list:
            temp.append(d2_key)
    D3[key]=temp
```

Output:

```
{0: ['Tim', 'Mike', 'Paul'], 1: ['Jack', 'Tommy']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

```
D1 = {0:[1, 2, 3], 1: [0,4]}
D2 = {'Jack': 1, 'Mike': 2, 'Tim': 3, 'Paul': 4, 'Tommy': 5}

D2_inverted = {v: k for k, v in D2.iteritems()}

D3={}

for key in D1:
    temp = []
    for value in D1[key]:
        temp.append(D2_inv[value+1])
    D3[key] = temp

print D3
```

Iterate the keys from D1;

Create a temporary list to store the values you wish to assign to the new dict, and fill it with the desired values from D2. (inverted its keys and values for simplicity);

Assign to D3.